# mysql, php jquery.autocomplete single row search using multipule :term words

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Im working on an autocomplete for a form I'm doing. My question is, how do I pass more than one search :term from jQuery into the mysql SELECT query? Like:

```
$search_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
```

then:

```
$query = "SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE :term AND
ProductName like :term";
```

But say in the cloumn ProductName a product example would be:

```
Red Wagon with Gold Rims
```

I can get it to search for "Red Wagon" or "Gold Rims". But I want to be able to enter:

```
Red Gold
```

and have the same ProductName come up. How would I make the words break up and search like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the term and then do the query like this:

```
SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE :term[0] AND ProductName LIKE :term[1]
```

Comment: I'm not following with you on that. How would I split the term from 
    $search_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";